# Loading a UIImageView subclass from a custom cell

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uiimageview

I am not sure if this is a Storyboard Bug. I have created a project with a custom cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HomeGameTurnCell";
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomeTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

The custom cell has some image views. One of the image views is a subclass.

```
@interface HomeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet RoundedProfilePicture *profilePictureImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *turnThumbnailImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastPlayedLabel;

@end
```

The RoundedProfilePicture subclass simply has the following:

```
-(id)init {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupView
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
}
```

What I am finding is that the RoundedProfilePicture methods are not being called. Within the storyboard I have setup one prototype cell and the correct identifier. I also have the image view set as the correct Custom class. But it doesn't seem to take effect, is there something I am missing/could check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when a UIimageView is subclassed and called from the storyboard a different method is called for the init.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    // As the subclassed UIImageView class is called from storyboard the initWithCoder is overwritten instead of init
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This resolves the issue of the rounded profile view not being called.

Answer (score 0):

When you are reusing an element you should override UITableViewCell method:

```
 -(void)prepareForReuse
```

instead of init. It will called each time.

If you want one time initialization you should do it in: initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
   return self;
}
```

From apple docs:

> If you registered a class for the specified identifier and a new cell must be created, this method initializes the cell by calling its initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method. For nib-based cells, this method loads the cell object from the provided nib file. If an existing cell was available for reuse, this method calls the cell’s prepareForReuse method instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how this is implemented, do you have an example of this over the current? Also, would this specific change effect the issue of the UIImageView class not being loaded?

Comment: I updated my answer - just instead of - (id) init use my initWithStyle

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry to be a pain, but I didn't actually understand the first part how the prepareForReuse is used for my context. I had actually tried changing the init for the Cell from initWithStyle to the init to see if any difference was made, but I can change that back..

Comment: Also - I think you are looking at the wrong init, the init in my question is actually for the UIimageView subclass init.

Comment: Oh right. So you need to add the initWithStyle I'm talking about to HomeTableViewCell. PrepareForReuse will be called on HomeTableViewCell by UITableView automatically each time it has to be prepared for reusing. Just create a function and debug it with some NSLog to check that.